# Unity: How can I get the width of a gameobject?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to make sure a gameobject (2D sprite, say, panda) stays to the left of another (say, bamboo), regardless of the former's size. I thought I could take the bamboo's location, and deduct the width of the panda from it.

Something like this:

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
foreach (GameObject panda in midBambooStack)
{
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(midBamboo.transform.position.x - panda.transform.lossyScale.x, panda.transform.position.y, panda.transform.position.z);
    panda.transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

But what I end up is that the panda goes right in the middle of the bamboo, so I'm assuming the `lossyScale.x` bit is wrong.

[image]

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here's my hierarchy, if it means something.

[image]

Comment: is there any rotation on the pandas?

Comment: @Timelord64, nope, I disabled them, because I had issues with dragging and dropping and rigidbodies.

Comment: are you decreasing or increasing scale? is there are any parent-child or the sprite is root?

Comment: @SP. Scale? I'm sorry, I don't think I understand your question. Each of those pandas are a different gameobject. I updated the question with a pic of my hierarchy.

Comment: what happens if you just use regular scale? `Transform.lossyScale` specifically gets you the global scale, but in your case, the pandas are not children of any other object. Since they do not inherit a scale from any other object, you should be fine with regular scale. I believe @SP means did you load in the smallest panda, and scale it up to the larger sizes, or load in the largest panda, and scale it down to the smaller sizes.

Comment: @Timelord64, the only other option is `transform.localScale`, and it does the same thing. Tried it with Rect too, but it didn't change anything. I did the smallest panda first, and copy pasted it, making it larger per paste.

Answer (score 3):

This will rely on the Pixel Per Unit value of your sprite.  If you do not have a 1:1 ratio, then a value of "1" for your LocalScale.x will not be the same width as your sprite.

Either set the sprite's Pixel Per Unit value to a 1:1 ratio, or manually calculate the ratio multiplier:

```
float PixelUnits;

private void CalculatePixelUnits()
{
    PixelUnits = Sprite.rect.width / Sprite.bounds.size.x;
}
```

In the above code you would pass in your Panda sprite.

With this value you should then be able to position these Pandas properly:

```
foreach (GameObject panda in midBambooStack)
{
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(midBamboo.transform.position.x - panda.transform.localScale.x * PixelUnits, panda.transform.position.y, panda.transform.position.z);
    panda.transform.position = newPosition;
}
```